# Text is not responsive for separate paragraphs (html, css)

Tags: html, css

how do i make each line under the "resume" responsive in a way that when the window gets smaller it stays within the line and doesn't go all the way to the left. i tried a few things but i can't seem to get it. go to resume and see lines for where the issue is. i hope the text itself makes it clear. thanks in advance!

```
ex. of what i want when window gets smaller:
title: "this is title"
       "this is the 
       second line"
       "this is the third
       line"
```

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body .container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      min-width:100%;
    }

    .scroll {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      scroll-snap-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    /* NAVIGATION BAR */

    #main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /*background-image: url(x.jpg);*/
        background-size: cover;
    }

    nav {
      position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: #fff;
        line-height: 80px;
      z-index: 99;
    }

    nav ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

    nav ul li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: 0.8s all;
    }


    nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: gray;
        padding: 30px;
    }

    nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }


    /* HOME NAME */

    .name {
      font-family: sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* SECTIONS */

    .box {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      padding: 70px;
      display: flex;
      padding-top: 20%;
    }

    .box .imgPro {
      width: 150px;
      flex: 0 0 150px;
    }

    .box .imgPro img {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .box .content {
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .box .content h2 {
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* RESUME/TIMELINE */

.box-tl {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.content-tl {
  width: 65%;
  height: 40vh;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

.box-tl .content-tl h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   outline: none;
}

.tl-container {
   width: 30%;
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 50px 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   transform: translateX(230%) translateY(10%);
}

.tl-container:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -1px;
   width: 2px;
   height: 100%;
   background: #CCD1D9;
   z-index: 1
}

.timeline-block {
   width: -webkit-calc(10% + 8px);
   width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px);
   width: calc(50% + 8px);
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-pack: justify;
   -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
   -moz-box-pack: justify;
   justify-content: space-between;
   clear: both;
}

.timeline-block-right {
   float: right;
}

.timeline-block-left {
   float: left;
   direction: rtl
}

.marker {
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 2px solid #F5F7FA;
   background: #4FC1E9;
   margin-top: 10px;
   z-index: 9999
}

.timeline-content {
   height: 16vh;
   width: 95%;
   padding: 0 15px;
   color: #666
}

.timeline-content h3 {
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: 500
}

.timeline-content span {
   font-size: 13px;
   color: #a4a4a4;
}

.timeline-content p {
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   word-spacing: 1px;
   color: #888;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .tl-container:before {
      left: 8px;
      width: 2px;
   }
   .timeline-block {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
   }
   .timeline-block-right {
      float: none;
   }

   .timeline-block-left {
      float: none;
      direction: ltr;
   }
}



/* SPACING WITHIN PARAGRAPH */
tab1 { 
  padding-left: 5ch; 
}

tab2 { 
  padding-left: 7ch;
}

p
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initialpscale=1.0">
    <title> title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- link for back to top button -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  </head>

<body>
  <button id="back-to-top-btn"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-up"></i></button>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="scroll">
      <nav>
      <!-- <img src="x.png" width="200" height="80"> for top-left logo -->
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#main">Home</a></li><!--
          --><li><a href="#about">About</a></li><!--
          --><li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li><!--
          --><li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li><!--
          --><li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <h1 class="name">TITLE</a></h1>
    </div>

    <section id="resume" class="scroll">

        <div class="box-tl">
          <div class="content-tl">
            <h2>Resume</h2>
            <p><b>Lorem:</b> Lorem ipsum<tab1>jan 2020 - feb 2020</tab1></p><!---
            --><p><tab2>THIS LINE HERE, DO NOT WANT IT TO GO ALL THE WAY LEFT WHEN REDUCING WINDOW SIZE. SEE DESIRED OUTPUT AT THE TOP.</tab2></p><!--
            --><p><tab2>THIS LINE HERE, DO NOT WANT IT TO GO ALL THE WAY LEFT WHEN REDUCING WINDOW SIZE. SEE DESIRED OUTPUT AT THE TOP.</tab2></p>          
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tl-container">
          <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
            <div class="marker"></div>
            <div class="timeline-content">
               <h3>First Year</h3>
               <span>Some work experience</span>
               <p>Lorem</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
            <div class="marker"></div>
            <div class="timeline-content">
               <h3>Seconed Year</h3>
               <span>Some work experience</span>
               <p>Lorem</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
            <div class="marker"></div>
            <div class="timeline-content">
               <h3>Third Year</h3>
               <span>Some work experience</span>
               <p>Lorem</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
            <div class="marker"></div>
            <div class="timeline-content">
               <h3>Fourth Year</h3>
               <span>Some work experience</span>
               <p>Lorem</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
            <div class="marker"></div>
            <div class="timeline-content">
               <h3>Fifth Year</h3>
               <span>Some work experience</span>
               <p>Lorem</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: show on the screen which line you mean, pls

Comment: please see updated edit. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should solve it:

```
.box-tl .content-tl p,
.box-tl .content-tl span, {
    text-align: center;
}
```